# POP up window authentication without a source code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to access a pop-up authentication box in a internal link which i can t share as it is confidential, i tried the below code to access it, it works fine for a single link but i have multiple links which i have it under a loop.

```
    driver.get(links[i])
    time.sleep(2)
    window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
    driver.switch_to.window(window_before)
    shell = win32.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    time.sleep(2)
    shell.Sendkeys('username')
    shell.Sendkeys('{TAB}')
    shell.Sendkeys('password')
    shell.Sendkeys('{ENTER}')
    time.sleep(4)
#Second login page Enter password again and log in
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('p_t02').send_keys('password')
    logon = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='t10C']").click()
```

Problem: when it runs the second loop for the second link it actually skips to the below part and throws an error

```
    driver.get(links[i])
    time.sleep(2)
    window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
    driver.switch_to.window(window_before)
    shell = win32.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    time.sleep(2)
    shell.Sendkeys('username')
    shell.Sendkeys('{TAB}')
    shell.Sendkeys('password')
    shell.Sendkeys('{ENTER}')
    time.sleep(4)
```

it skips the above and goes to the below code and throws an error

```
#Second login page Enter password again and log in
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('p_t02').send_keys('password')
```

can anyone help me get past the authentication with another way
like without using the

```
shell = win32.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
```

Comment: Is the code you posted actual code or are you posting only a part (as in the ones within the loop)?  Assuming it's the code block inside a loop,  I'm not sure how it 'skips' to the ```password = ...``` line.  Also what error do you get?

Comment: so as the code is running i also use other applications in the background so i guess this would disturb the shell = win32.Dispatch("WScript.Shell") line as it send tab and strings, this is just my assumptions so not sure

Comment: and about the code skipping the first login page codes and moving to this part
#Second login page Enter password again and log in
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('p_t02').send_keys('password')
i get a element not found error

Comment: Please include that detail in your post.